# iOS App uses wrong default language for app name

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I try to set the default language for the app name (CFBundleDisplayName) to german as default but iOS displays the english name in case of the iPhone is set to any other language than german.

I already add a InfoPlist.strings for german and english and set the CFBundleDisplayName in each of them. In the XCode project I added both languages beside to Base Internationalization. In the Info.plist I set the `Localization native development region` also to Germany and in the Xcode project.pbxproj I set `developmentRegion` property to `de`.

After all of this the app name (CFBundleDisplayName) is still displayed in english if I choose for example only French.